# Not able to understand virtual base class constructor in case of multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

In below program in case if I change the sequence in Derived class "D" then I am getting different order of the constructors of base class.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class A {
      public :
            A ()
            {
                cout << "A()" <<endl;
            }
    };

    class B : virtual A{
      public :
            B ()
            {
                cout << "B()" << endl;
            }
    };

    class C : virtual B{
      public :
            C ()
            {
                cout << "C()" << endl;
            }
    };

Case (1)
========
    class D : public A, public B, public C
    {

    };

    int main()
    {
        D d;
        return 0;
    }
OUTPUT : 
A()
B()
A()
B()
C()

Case (2)
========
    class D : public C, public B, public A
    {

    };

    int main()
    {
        D d;
        return 0;
    }
OUTPUT :
A()
B()
C()
B()
A()

Case (3)
========
    class D : public B, public A, public C
    {

    };

    int main()
    {
        D d;
        return 0;
    }
OUTPUT :
A()
B()
B()
A()
C()
```

Please can anyone tell how constructors are called in case of virtual class concepts.

Comment: Not sure if you understand how virtual inheritance works: http://ideone.com/Ptaf5u

Comment: Why do you use private inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

> Please can anyone tell how constructors are called in case of virtual class concepts.

According to the [initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order), the virtual base class will be initialized at first.

> 1) If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base
>   classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>   (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as
>   they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

In all the 3 cases, class `D` is inheriting from `A`, `B`, and `C`, there're two virtual base classes in `D`, i.e. `A` inheritted via `B` and `C`, and `B` inheritted via `C`. And `A` will be initialized firstly because it's the most base class, so for all the 3 cases `A()` and `B()` will be printed out at first.

After that the direct base classes will initialized in left-to-right order. For the 1st case they'll be `A()` `B()` `C()`, for the 2nd case they'll be `B()` `C()` `A()`, for the 3rd case they'll be `B()` `A()` `C()`.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual bases are always initialized first in DFS post-order. This guarantees that the virtual A and B bases will be initialized first, and A before B since B is derived from A. After that, the three non-virtual bases A, B, C are simply initialized in declaration order as you would expect.